# How to correctly map 4 tables in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 4 tables

**Area:** it is a catalog where there are all the departments of an organization (parent)

**SubAreas**: It is a catalog where there are all the subAreas that belong to before catalog (Area), that is (child)

**personal:** Catalog where all the employees of the organization exist

**personal Area:** It is a table where there are all the relationships between the tables previously described

The business logic is simple, an employee can belong to one of several areas and only one subarea for each area to which they belong.

**Here my relationships**

[image]

These are my entities

**Personal**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal", catalog = "almacen", schema = "")
public class Personal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "curp")
    private String curp;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personal")
    private Set<PersonalArea> registrations = new HashSet<>();

}
```

**PersonalArea**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal_area", catalog = "almacen", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
public class PersonalArea {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personal_id")

    private Personal personal;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "area_id")
    private Area area;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subarea_id")
    private subArea subArea;
    
    private Date fechaCreacion;

}
```

**Area**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "area", catalog = "almacen", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
public class Area {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    private String nombreArea;
    @JsonIgnore

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "area")
    private Set<PersonalArea> registrations = new HashSet<>();


}
```

**SubArea**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_area", catalog = "almacen", schema = "")
public class subArea {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    private Long idArea;
    private String nombre;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personal")
    private Set<PersonalArea> registrations = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Actually I get something like this
As you can see, the json has two times the same personal who belongs to two areas and one subarea for each area... It's ok, but I don't want this json

```
{
    "items": [{
            "id": 1,
            "personal": {
                "id": 1,
                "curp": "AEMM680119HHGRRR03",
                "nombre": "MARIO RUBIZEL",
                "primerApellido": "ARTEAGA",
                "segundoApellido": "MORALES",
                "telefono": "7711263949",
                "fechaCreacion": null,
                "fechaModificacion": null
            },
            "area": {
                "id": 2,
                "nombreArea": "PERSONAL ADMINISTRATIVO"
            },
            "subArea": {
                "id": 1,
                "idArea": 2,
                "nombre": "CONTROL ESCOLAR"
            },
            "fechaCreacion": "2021-06-24T16:26:49.000+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "personal": {
                "id": 1,
                "curp": "AEMM680119HHGRRR03",
                "nombre": "MARIO RUBIZEL",
                "primerApellido": "ARTEAGA",
                "segundoApellido": "MORALES",
                "telefono": "7711263949",
                "fechaCreacion": null,
                "fechaModificacion": null
            },
            "area": {
                "id": 5,
                "nombreArea": "PERSONAL EXTERNO"
            },
            "subArea": {
                "id": 2,
                "idArea": 5,
                "nombre": "FOTOCOPIADO"
            },
            "fechaCreacion": "2021-06-24T16:26:49.000+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need my json something like this: Show just once personal and areas y subareas as child

```
{
        "items": [{
                "id": 1,
                "personal": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "curp": "AEMM680119HHGRRR03",
                    "nombre": "MARIO RUBIZEL",
                    "primerApellido": "ARTEAGA",
                    "segundoApellido": "MORALES",
                    "telefono": "7711263949",
                    "fechaCreacion": null,
                    "fechaModificacion": null
                },
                "area": [{
                        "id": 1,
                        "nombreArea": "DIRECTOR",
                        "subArea": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "idArea": 2,
                            "nombre": "CONTROL ESCOLAR"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "nombreArea": "PERSONAL EXTERNO",
                        "subArea": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "idArea": 5,
                            "nombre": "FOTOCOPIADO"
                        }
                    }

                ],
                "fechaCreacion": "2021-06-24T16:26:49.000+00:00"
            }

        ]
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Note that you only need annotations for _exceptions_. The column name is automatically assumed to match the property name, scalar types are assumed to be `@Basic`, etc. Why do you have `@XmlRootElement` if you're not using XML?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, I'm just copy and paste... I didn't see this mistake!! I think that is not relevante!